# Does momentum transport occur via diffusion (or random walks)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, kinetic-theory, gas, transport-phenomena

Consider a simple gas (or fluid) within a box at thermal equilibrium. I manage to give a kick to one particle within the gas, such that it acquires some momentum. After some time, it should be expected that this localized energy (or momentum) input would be just distributed such that Boltzmann distribution is recovered. But how does this recovery take place ?

The simplest mode of transport of this momentum disturbance could be for example a sound mode, that is, a sequence of kicks in the same direction of the initial kick is generated starting from the kicked particle. But I can also imagine that after the first kick, momentum is transferred in random walk slow manner. Here the momentum disturbance would be tracing a some kind of random trajectory instead of a linear trajectory as it would be for a sound mode.

How to know which kinds of modes are taking place (roughly depending on kick strength, density, temperature and so on..) ?

Comment: Viscosity is to momentum transport as diffusion is to density transport. Are you therefore asking for a microscopic explanation of viscosity?

Comment: Could you elaborate your analogy ? Maybe I can make sense of this because in hydrodynamic equations viscosity appears as coefficient of the Laplacian of velocity, while diffusivity appears as coefficient of the Laplacian of density.  But can you elaborate pictorially on your analogy ?

Comment: Look into [transport phenomena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_phenomena) for example.

Comment: This is helpful thanks.